# RSA cipher: ambiguous or break by eth root?

Tags: rsa

Confused about RSA message cipher: $c = m^e (mod\ n)$

So if $m^e$ can be greater than n, then you can get duplicate ciphers for the same message.   Most postings I've read say that $m^e$ must always be smaller than n to counteract.

But if $m^e$ is smaller than n, then $c = m^e$ and can just be decrypted by $\sqrt[e]{c}$.  Most postings I've read said that $m^e$ should be greater than n to counteract.

So it seems like there are only 2, differently broken, options.  How is this reconciled in practice?
(My assumption is that "padding" reconciles this, but I'm not sure how.)

Answer (score 6):

Due to poor use of notation, the question uses an incorrect (or at least incomplete) definition of textbook RSA encryption, which actually defines ciphertext $c$ for a given $m$ as:$$c=m^e\bmod n$$This can be read as: “ $c$ equals [pause] $m$ to the $e$<sup>th</sup> power reduced modulo $n$ ” where *power* or/and *reduced* can be left implied, and the pause emphasizes that $c$ is the result of the final modular reduction. It means that $c$ is the remainder of the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) of $m^e$ by $n$, which unambiguously defines $c$ for given $m\ge0$, $e>0$, and $n>0$. It equivalently means that $0\le c<n$ and $c\equiv m^e\pmod n$, as defined below.

The notation $c\equiv m^e\pmod n$ can be read as: “ $c$ is equivalent to $m$ to the $e$<sup>th</sup> power [pause] modulo $n$ ” where the pause emphasizes that *modulo* pairs with the earlier *equivalent*, rather than with an implied *reduction*. For non-zero $n$, it means that $m^e-c$ is a multiple of $n$. There are infinitely many $c$ matching this.

Notation rule: when $\mod\;$ is without an opening parenthesis immediately on its left, and without an $\;\equiv\;$ sign anywhere on its left, it means *reduction modulo*, or equivalently *remainder*. Otherwise, it tends to mean *equivalence modulo*. The later is unambiguous when $\mod\;$ is with an opening parenthesis immediately on its left, and with an $\;\equiv\;$ sign somewhere on its left.

---

Indeed, in order to avoid guess of $m$ as $\sqrt[e]c$, it is necessary that $m^e\ge n$ holds, at least with overwhelming odds. The recommendable method to ensure this is not to directly avoid small $m$; rather, it is to pick $m$ essentially as a random integer with $0\le m<n$. It is safer, and practiced, to choose $m$ in the later way, and then use $m$ as a key to a symmetric cipher protecting the confidentiality of the actual message. Other methods exist that allow conveying with $c$ a small message $M$ reversibly turned into an integer $m$ that is random enough, see [PKCS#1 encryption schemes](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=15).

Comment: Sorry that I have difficulty to understand your sentences "... pick m ... as a random integer with 0 <=m<n..." and "... use m as a key to a symmetric cipher ...". If n, as commonly recommended today, is of the order of 2000 bits, that would imply using a really huge symmetric key in most cases, wouldn't it? (Common symmetric ciphers have on the other hand fairly small and rather fixed key sizes.)

Comment: @Mok-KongShen: indeed, one can not directly use $m$ as a key to a standard symmetric cipher, like AES in some mode. First, $m$ would go thru a key derivation function. That could be: apply SHA-256 to a representation of $m$ as octet string of prescribed size, and use the hash as key for AES in some mode. In a hurry, keeping the low 256 bits of $m$ would do.

Comment: Using RSA not directly to encrypt plaintext but  to transfer a secret key of a block cipher is certainly the "standard" and processing-efficient way. However (1) Not all encryption applications need very high processing efficiency, (2) The additional involvement of a block cipher and hashing IMHO complicates the entire matter both in coding and conceptually (for understanding of the users). Hence I have a code (destined for the common users who have only small volumes of plaintexts to encrypt) that involves basically nothing but RSA in Ex.3 and 3S of s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/

Answer (score 5):

> So if $m^e$ can be greater than n, then you can get duplicate ciphers for the same message.

I'm not exactly certain what you mean, but:

- If you mean that one particular message $m$ might be encrypted in two different ways, no, that's not the case, at least, not in the way that you mean.  If you have a specific value for $m$, $e$ and $n$, then $m^e \bmod n$ has a unique value between 0 and $n-1$.  Now, this "one particular message may be encrypted in multiple ways" is a property we actually do want; in practice, we handle it in the padding (which maps the message we actually want to encrypt to the value we present to the RSA algorithms).
- If you mean that there might be two distinct messages $m_1$ and $m_2$ that would encrypt to the same ciphertext, no, that's not the case (unless $e$ happens to not be relatively prime to $\phi(n)$; when we select $e$ and $n$, we are always take care to make sure that $e$ and $\phi(n)$ are relatively prime).

> Most postings I've read said that $m^e$ should be greater than n to counteract.

That is indeed the case; in fact, deliberately selecting a small $m$ is a bad idea (because it may allow other attacks based on the homomorphic properties of RSA).